# Check if the user has logged in for the first time without using django-allauth

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have found a lot of questions here asking about the same topic but they all have one thing in common, i.e. Django-allauth. But my project uses djoser. I want users to add some additional information to their profile only when they log in for the first time. 
I can not use the comparison of

```
user.last_login == user.date_joined
```

as when I log in the last login date changes, and I want the user to log in so they can make the changes.

I am using Django 1.7 and [djoser](https://github.com/sunscrapers/djoser) for the login and authentication purpose.

Comment: Why don't you simply check if that additional information exists in the profile?

Comment: @selcuk because its optional, they can or cannot have this information in their profile. But they are only allowed to add once (at first time login)

Comment: I don't understand why you can't use the last_login? if they have never logged in then this would be none

Comment: nope, last_login is same as date_joined. But after the user logs in (even if its for the first time) the last_login changes to current_datetime. I am using django 1.7

Comment: You should probably show how you're using it because it sounds like you have other things going on that are tampering with it

Comment: can you show me the exact usage of this field? how do i detect if the user is logged in first time through this field? Can you please explain me the logic?

Comment: @Selcuk Thanks its working!! :) you can write it in the answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply add a new `BooleanField` (say, named `is_previously_logged_in`) with `default=False` to your profile model and check if it is still `False` at every login. You can then set it to `True` so that you don't show the profile information to the user twice.

Answer (score 0):

This can also be achieved by checking for the built-in `user.last_login` field. It will be `None` until the user logs in for the first time.

The best place to check this that I could fine is in the `login` method of the account adapter:

```py
class CustomAccountAdapter(DefaultAccountAdapter):
    def login(self, request, user):
        is_first_login = user.last_login is None
        super().login(request, user)
        if is_first_login:
            # First login, do something
```

If you're not using a custom adapter yet, you'll need to add the following to your Django settings file:

```py
ACCOUNT_ADAPTER = 'my.package.CustomAccountAdapter'
```