# How to add a form that appear only one time for new users and then back to regular form

Tags: python, django

I want to create a form with extra fields :

this is the models.py for regular form :

Boutique :

```
class Boutique(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, default=1)
    logo = models.FileField(max_length=250)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

form.py :

```
class BoutiqueForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Boutique
        fields = ['name', 'logo']
```

Views.py :

```
def create_boutique(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return render(request, 'produit/login.html')
    else:
        form = BoutiqueForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            boutique = form.save(commit=False)
            boutique.user = request.user
            boutique.logo = request.FILES['logo']
            file_type = boutique.logo.url.split('.')[-1]
            file_type = file_type.lower()
            if file_type not in IMAGE_FILE_TYPES:
                context = {
                    'boutique': boutique,
                    'form': form,
                    'error_message': 'Image file must be PNG, JPG, or JPEG',
                }
                return render(request, 'produit/create_boutique.html', context)
            boutique.save()
            return render(request, 'produit/detail.html', {'boutique': boutique})
        context = {
            "form": form,
        }
        return render(request, 'produit/create_boutique.html', context)
```

form_template.html :

```
{% for field in form %}
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
        <span class="text-danger small">{{ field.errors }}</span>

    </div>
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2">{{ field.label_tag}}</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">{{ field }}</div>
</div>{% endfor %}
```

i want to add a table boutique_commerçant that containt 2 extra fields facebook_link and entreprise ... that appear in create_boutique.html only one time for new registred user...

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35769798/check-if-the-user-has-logged-in-for-the-first-time-without-using-django-allauth).

You can add an extra field which defaults to False and is set to True if your two fields are saved. This way you can check if the information exists, and only show the form when not.